# Getting only the DIRECT InnerText of an IHTMLElement

Tags: c#, .net, browser

Consider the following html code:

`<div id='x'><div id='y'>Y content</div>X content</div>`

I'd like to extract only the content of 'x'. However, its innerText property includes the content of 'y' as well. I tried iterating over its *children* and *all* properties but they only return the inner tags.

How can I access through the IHTMLElement interface only the actual data of 'x'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [childNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537445(VS.85).aspx) collection to return child elements and textnodes
You need to QI IHTMLDomNote from IHTMLelement for that.

Comment: Thanks :). That sortof worked. I'm pasting the final code in the question for others.

It didn't completely work though since the inner #text has some <br>'s insides so now I have to put it together, thus, some string manipulation is needed regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like:

```
function getText(this) {
    var txt = this.innerHTML;
    txt.replace(/<(.)*>/g, "");
    return txt;
}
```

Since this.innerHTML returns

```
<div id='y'>Y content</div>X content
```

the function getText would return

```
X content
```

Maybe this'll help.

Comment: Well, yes, that would... But I really wanted to avoid using regex... Isn't there something more direct under IE DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code as suggested by Sheng (just a part of the sample, of course):

```
mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection c = ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)(wbBrowser.Document)).getElementsByTagName("div");
foreach (IHTMLElement div in c)
{
    if (div.className == "lyricbox")
    {
        IHTMLDOMNode divNode = (IHTMLDOMNode)div;

        IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection children = (IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection)divNode.childNodes;

        foreach (IHTMLDOMNode child in children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(child.nodeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since innerText() doesn't work with ie, there is no real way i guess.
Maybe try server-side solving the issue by creating content the following way:

```
<div id='x'><div id='y'>Y content</div>X content</div>
<div id='x-plain'>_plain X content_</div>
```

"*Plain X content*" represents your c# generated content for the element.
Now you gain access to the element by refering to getObject('x-plan').innerHTML().